# Add a 0 to the end of a decimal number to make sure it's always 2 decimals?

Tags: jquery, math, rounding

I am using the following code to work out an inc and ext VAT price:

```
$('#totalexvat').text(totalprice);
var vat = totalprice / 100 * 17.5;
vat = roundNumber(vat,2);
$('#totalincvat').text(totalprice-vat);
```

Sometimes I get .3 or .9 instead of what I would like to be .30 or .90 because it's money, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at this: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/ since you're using jQuery already.

Answer (score 2):

try [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/ToFixed)

Comment: I wish I could select your answer - this is by far a better answer than "look some where else."